Getting resource not found error while creating SF lead
I am getting an error while I try to create a new lead in SF. No issues while obtaining access token

Is your dev org/sandbox/scratch org on the Winter '25 preview? If not, or if you don't need any of the new features being included in Winter '25, then you should be using v61.0 (or an earlier API version as long as you don't go below v31.0) instead.
